# Nodemon - waiting for file changes before start

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Nodemon shows the following error when I try to run `npm start`. I tried some methods which are already available on the internet including turning off the node server from the task manager and checking files are available at that location but nothing worked.

```
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): backend\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../nodemon.json'
Require stack:
- F:\Rancho Labs\WebAppfinal\backend\routers\Payment.js
- F:\Rancho Labs\WebAppfinal\backend\routers\index.js
- F:\Rancho Labs\WebAppfinal\backend\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Rancho Labs\WebAppfinal\backend\routers\Payment.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Rancho Labs\WebAppfinal\backend\routers\index.js:11:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Rancho Labs\WebAppfinal\backend\server.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'F:\\Rancho Labs\\WebAppfinal\\backend\\routers\\Payment.js',
    'F:\\Rancho Labs\\WebAppfinal\\backend\\routers\\index.js',
    'F:\\Rancho Labs\\WebAppfinal\\backend\\server.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: What's the full stack? Please post as text not images. Looks like an import can't be found but without the code it's impossible to say

Comment: Please check it now